# Mapping exception after install SonataMediaBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to setup and use SonataMediaBundle for use inside SonataAdminBundle. I read and follow every step in [docs for SMB](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html). When I run the command:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataMediaBundle
```

By default this create the Bundle in `app/` folder so manually I move into `src/` folder where it should be. Now every time I try to access to my application I get this error:

> MappingException: The class
>   'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity

And I don't know why, I check everywhere looking for references and didn't found nothing. Can any help me to fix this or give me a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reads and try several things I found where the error was. In my doctrine config I have:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
#   auto_mapping: true
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                SonataMediaBundle: ~
```

By removing the auto_mapping clause, I no longer register UserBundle in the doctrine’s mapping directories. Hence it cannot find your User entity. So solution was either uncomment the `auto_mapping: true` from your config and comment the `entity_manager.default.mappings` part, or explicitly specify your User bundle in the section. So I pick the first one and my code looks like this now:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
#    entity_managers:
#        default:
#            mappings:
#                ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
#                SonataMediaBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

remove it again and run following command, `php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle`... You forgot the `--dest=src` and just by moving the files you won't have changed all the namespaces.

Comment: I generated the bundle as you suggested after I run the command:

`#php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "5" queries were executed`

Clear the cache by deleting all in `app/cache/` folder but error remains:

`MappingException: The class 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity`

I don't know what is causing this, any other idea?

Comment: can you update your question with your composer.json and did you actually follow the install [instructions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html) because the `schema:update`command is one of the last steps...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution where it should be:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    SonataMediaBundle: ~
```

auto_mapping: true must be into doctrine, orm, entity_managers, default section and not into doctrine, orm.